# How to setup XSRF protection in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, csrf

I am developing an application using angularJs, resources and jersey rest api's. And I want to implement xsrf protection in my project. Please suggest a better example. I got one example here, but it uses ColdFusion. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2568-Preventing-Cross-Site-Request-Forgery-CSRF-XSRF-With-AngularJS-And-ColdFusion.htm

Comment: How do you authenticate users? Could you give more detail on the application?

Comment: I am using spring security to authenticate user. I have a jsp login page and the rest api's (/app/rest/**) are filtered in spring security. The main page gets loaded once the user logs in, there is a controller that brings all the user info and put it in sessionStorage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Different from given example, you need to do 2 things:

1. When the main page gets loaded once the user logs in, you need to set a session cookie with name XSRF-COOKIE. Then AngularJS will do the rest by appending a header to every request as stated in documentation (1)
2. You need to validate every call to your rest API in back-end (for example with an interceptor) by comparing the token in cookie and the one in header. The logic is described on the page you referenced

(1) To take advantage of this, your server needs to set a token in a JavaScript readable session cookie called XSRF-TOKEN on the first HTTP GET request. [CSRF Protection section in Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#security-considerations)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was using spring security 3.0. I am planning to upgrade it. Will get back to u after that.

Answer (score 0):

**Incase this is your code in jsp/ html page which sets the header and token:**

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

**You can configure the csrf headers for all ajax requests as flollows:**

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

angular.module("app", [])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common[header] = token;
}]);
```

**And then your http request code will go as follows:**

```
$http({
    url: "loadMyData.htm",
    method: "POST",
}).success(function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: You just defeated the entire security premise for using Angular's method to protect against Cross-Site Request Forgery.  The whole point of using the cookie is so that malicious JavaScript cannot read its contents to get at the token stored inside.  By providing the token in the HTML, malicious JavaScript can now extract said token out of the DOM bypassing the security entirely.

Comment: "One might ask why the CsrfToken isn't stored in a cookie. This is because there are known exploits in which headers (i.e. set cookies) can be set by another domain. Another disadvantage is that by removing the state (i.e. the timeout) you lose the ability to forcibly terminate the token if something got compromised." 
[source](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/#timeouts)

Comment: @UncleCodeMonkey The application must be able to access the CSRF token in order to include it in the HTTP request headers, correct? So, if the application can access the token, then malicious JavaScript on the *same domain* should be able to access it too, correct? I'm not arguing that this is a better answer, but I don't think the criticism you have raised is valid. If an application is exploited via XSS, then the CSRF token is also likely compromised, correct? (Am I missing something?)

Answer (score 0):

create interceptor with below command.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
     const cookie = this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
    request = request.clone({
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'XSRF-TOKEN': cookie,

      }),
    withCredentials: true
 });
 return next.handle(request);
}
```