# Fix "Cross-Site Request Forgery" vulnerability in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, security, csrf

I working on resolving vulnerabilities on an AngularJS application.
The Cross-Site Request Forgery vulnerability is there in my app.

I have put the XSRF-TOKEN in cookies

Inside **app.js** module:

```
$http(req).then(function(result) {
    $cookieStore.put('XSRF-TOKEN', result.data.session);
}, function(error) {
       console.log(error);
   }
);

...
...

if ($cookieStore.get('XSRF-TOKEN') == null || $cookieStore.get('XSRF-TOKEN') == "") {
    rejection.status = 403;
}
```

The vulnerability is not going. I have followed this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22498311/8337391 . But the issue is still persisting.
It will be helpful if anybody can give some useful tips please.

Comment: Hi anybody has any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you are just checking the XSRF value is there, that's not what you do with XSRF tokens - you need to generate a random value for the token and then check its value on each access. Also, what tool is indicating there's an XSRF issue?